# Ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ionic-framework

[image: screen shot cmd]

[image: screen shot Environment variable]

how to resolve can i fixed it . i already install cordova and ionic global

C:\Users\sever>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\sever\ionic
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\sever\ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\sever\node_modu
les\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v5.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sever\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5068-24aad619\unpack-77f32b4
3\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sever\AppData\
Local\Temp\npm-5068-24aad619\unpack-77f32b43\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sever\AppData\
Local\Temp\npm-5068-24aad619\unpack-77f32b43\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sever\npm-debug.log

Comment: try to add more information what you try and instead of photos try to write command and what you adding to environment

Comment: got any solution ?

Comment: i edit my question
1.ANDROID_HOME : E:\android-sdk-windows
2.ANT_HOME : C:\apache-ant-1.9.7
3.APPDATA : :\Users\sever\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin
i think this is system variable problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to run

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and

```
npm install -g ionic
```

And then in windows you have to reopen the cmd window, else the changes aren't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is npm -v is 3.10.8, which is lower than 4, causing me `npm install -g ionic cordova` always fail. Giving error like below.
'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, ...

After I run `npm install -g npm` everything seem fine, and now I can run `npm install -g ionic cordova`